# I have a model with many, many spikes on it and they need to be rigged. Any possible way to do this?

Tags: rigging, bones

Now, you can call this 'thing' a disaster:

[image: A model I made.]

Now, as crazy as it looks, I'm trying to RIG this, every spike. The problem here is that rigging every bone like placing it everywhere will take a **colossal** amount of time. So the thing I'm aiming for is that is there any possible way to rig this fastly? I'm not trying to push your knowledge on Blender but I need the rigging for realism for a disease (making an animation).

I need a quick way (I don't care if it's hard, anyway) to rig all the spikes on this model, can anybody help?

**Any helpful answers are appreciated...**

Comment: What is your intended use, are you making an animation inside Blender? Do you have a video reference for the motion of spikes? Chances are skeletal rigging isn't the best approach to this but honestly, it's not the rigging of 30 spikes I'd be worried about but managing them in animations.

Comment: What is the motion of the spikes/tentacles?  Highly coordinated motion or random?  What is your expertise/familiarity level in Python or other animation tools in Blender?

Comment: Can you post the blend? I'd like to try that

Answer (score 1):

First I would try using [snap to volume](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#snap-element), this can make rigging fingers easy. Snap one end of a bone to the base of a spike and the other to the tip. Subdivide the bone and then snap the new joints at points along the spike.

If volume snapping doesn't work very well, you can use the 3d cursor for [snapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#snap-menu), a bit long and tedious for this many items. Select verts around base of a spike, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> click if you have a clean edge ring around each, otherwise you can select two, three or four verts that surround a centre point and snap the cursor to that, go into the rig and add a bone in that position (a new bone will be created at the 3d cursor), then select the tip of the spike and snap the cursor to that, then select and snap the opposite end of the bone to the tip. The same thing can be done at mid points to align multiple bones along the spike.

Comment: This may come off a little stupid, but I cannot get Snap to Volume to work right. I active the snap tool, go into Edit Mode on my armature and it should snap to the volume center, right? 
Can you maybe show me how to do it?